# Perl script to penetrate to sub directories

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a long list of sub directories such that C0/C1/C2...C354. It individually contains respective files. I am trying to change the ownership of the directories (not the files in the directories). This is what I have wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::Find;

my @directories;
find sub{
    print "$File::Find::name";
    print "\n";
    return unless -d;
    next if (m/^\./);
    push @directories, $File::Find::name;
}, ".";

foreach my $file (@directories){
    my $cmd = qx |chown deep:deep $file|;
}
```

It goes uptil C0/C1 and stops penetrating into the other files. Is there a problem with my linux file-system or there is a limitation to the File::Find module in Perl. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: If you're on linux/unix you don't need to write code to do this.  The `chown` command has a "recursive" option (`-R`) to do a deep chown on an entire tree.

Comment: So, you want to change just the directory ownership on all directories on a directory tree?  `find $STARTDIR -type d -exec chown deep:deep {} \;`

Comment: @JimGarrison: Using `chown -R` will change files as well as directories, contrary to the requirements in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Then use `find|chown` -- none of this requires writing code.

Comment: @deep: you can use the Perl function [`chown`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html) with the UID for user `deep` and GID for group `deep` and your list of directories, without invoking the external program even once, let alone many times.  If you prefer, you could invoke `chown` (the function) in the sub you pass to `find`.  Is your directory structure 300 levels deep?

Comment: Thank you for your comments..But it is not yet printing all the directories in "$File::Find::Name". Is there some error in the file system if the list the of sub directories is way to long. Thanks.

Comment: There could be problems with overlong directory paths, yes.  Specifically, you could run out of file descriptors (each directory level requires an extra file descriptor).  I'd expect to see output from the print statements in the wanted sub until it runs into the limit, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . Thank you for your reply. The sub directories which I am working on is mounted. The script works fine for the directories on the machine. Any suggestion on how to work arond for mounted directories. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop inside the function given to File::Find::find but you still use "next" inside it. This will cause it to look for a loop outside the function and it will probably find it somewhere inside File::Find, thus causing erratic behavior.
You probably want to have a "return" instead of a "next".

And there should have been a (runtime) warning about it.